# Replace a word by another without using replace function

Tags: java, string, replace, words, randomaccessfile

I need to replace a word by another without using `replace` and `replaceAll` functions in a text.

If the word I want to replace has the same length as the original one there aren't any problems. The problem is when the word I want to replace is longer or shorter than the original.

For example: I want to replace "one" by "thirteen" in the string "I have one dog". This is what I tried to do (I use `RandomAccessFile` class):

```
RandomAccessFile r  = new RandomAccessFile("toto.txt","rw")
r.seek(position); // imagine that position is the right cursor which take place under the o from the word "one"
r.writeBytes("thirteen");
```

When I try this I erase the words after dog because "thirteen" is longer than "one"..

Same problem if the word I want to replace is shorter than the original. I replaced the remaining letters by blank letters but I have ugly blank spaces...

How can I proceed?

Comment: What's the specific reason that you can't use replace? Is it an assignment? Do you have memory limitations?

Comment: Yes, it's an assignment.

Comment: What do you actually need to modify? Do you need to modify a string in memory, or a file?

Comment: I just need to modify a word (a string if you want) by another in a given text (file).

Answer (score 1):

This is how i would do it:

- For every line in file
- Replace what you want in the line
- Write line into temporary file
- Write everything back from temporary file into original file

If you file is not big, you can just keep the lines in memory instead of writing in temporary file.

Instead of writing everything back, you could delete original file and rename temporary one to original filename.

Answer (score 1):

You could read the whole file and then use String's `replace`. There are two alternative outcomes:

1. the new string is shorter - in which case we pad the string at the end
2. the new string is longer or the same length - this should not be a problem as `RandomAccessFile` will extend the file.

We write the `newString` from position 0 - `RandomAccessFile` works like an array and so the contents are overwritten.

```
RandomAccessFile r  = new RandomAccessFile("toto.txt","rw");

//read the content 
byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)r.length()];
r.read(buffer);
String str = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

//replace and pad right to get at least the same length
String newString = str.replaceAll("one","three");
str = String.format("%1$"+str.length()+ "s", newString);

//write back to the file
r.seek(0);
r.writeBytes(newString);
r.close();
```

Comment: I understand your method thanks a lot but I can't use replaceAll function. In fact, the aim of my assignment is to search every word who match with another one (I implemented an algorithm given) and replace it. In a nutshell I have to do replaceAll job on my own way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to work with String like with array: use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer–Moore_string_search_algorithm and replace characters. Of course, you need to modify array length.

Answer (score 0):

`RandomAccessFile` works like an array. You can overwrite values but not insert anything in the middle. What you can do is `setLength` to compensate and shift the existing text forward as much as you need to.

I'm not sure it's a "better" solution in any way than what Mats391 suggested. It might be the shortest (but not simplest) way.

Comment: Can I insert anything in the middle with another class ? Like BufferedWriter for example ?